# Drupal: create a node with employee working hours

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I have a bit complicated task.

**1.** I need to create a node with employee working hours (it's gonna be created for all users with role "employee"), which looks like this:

```
    Monday:    From __ : __ To __ : __
    Tuesday:   From __ : __ To __ : __
    Wednesday: From __ : __ To __ : __
    etc.
```

So, I'll have to create probably 14 CCK fields (monday_from, monday_to, tuesday_from...) or more to store the day of the week and workging hours (hours and minutes).

**2.** I need to add a view with exposed filters, where visitors can filter employees by day of the week and working hours.

What kind of field should I use for working hours? How could views filtering described above be achieved?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at the [Office hours module](http://drupal.org/project/office_hours). I don't know if you can use exposed filters on it, but it should get you most of the way.

Comment: Unfortunately, Office hours module has problems with Views integration. Got bunch of errors while trying to add an exposed filter for Office hour field.

Comment: You will need to create your own exposed filter for it, as it hasn't been made for the module yet. You can contribute it back to the module when you get it working.
That would be the best long term solution.