# Drupal module for complex hours of operation / office hours

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-modules, cck

**Background:**

I am building a website in Drupal that links together a wide variety of social service providers for the purposes of discovery, collaboration, and all that good stuff. The goal is to make a website that is simple to browse for consumers of these services and simple to update for providers of these services. The beta has been very well received, but I want to switch to a different information schema before the site goes live.

**Specific question:**

I am looking for a module (or other solution) that...

- Stores this data in Drupal (i.e., no GCal)
- Supports a wide variety of repeats
- Is intuitive for people editing the node (no Cron-style interfaces, please!)

I have looked into several modules on drupal.org and none seem to meet all of these criteria. I've also searched here, and while this question is similar:

[Drupal: create a node with employee working hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794149/drupal-create-a-node-with-employee-working-hours)

my needs are too complex for the offered solution. Some of these providers have "hours" such as "the third Wednesday of every month", or "open during Winter months", or separate hotline & office hours. Likewise, the Date Repeat module doesn't cut it as stands currently.

I'm comfortable hacking what I need into an existing module - I just don't want to duplicate effort! If you have a suggestion on what module might be a good starting point, I'd appreciate that input, too.

Comment: Wrote a long answer of the plan I'm actively working on, then saw Date Repeat API won't cut your mustard. As far as I know, Date Repeat API is the most advanced functionality for what you describe. Patching it for more powerful options would be my first step.

Answer (score 1):

An ultra-structured data entry for opening hours is only useful for advanced searching. If you don't need to do advanced searching by open hours (eg. "Find every office that is open at 4PM on the 3rd Wednesday of August"), have you considered just using free text for entering this information?

For a shopping mall project, I modified http://drupal.org/project/office_hours for standard/repeating hours, then fell back to a textbox for the "weird" hours where if populated it would display the textbox instead of the Office Hours block.